# Replace method doesn't replace dashes to empty string

Tags: c#, .net, replace

I'm trying to hash a file using SHA1. The result looks like this: `B7-DB-B9-93-E7-2F-6F-EB-6D-CD-CC-A8-DE-D2-F1-01-6E-8A-53-BC`

How to I replace dashes to empty string or just remove them?

The code trying to replace the dashes, but it seems like it don't change anything and dashes are still in place.

```
using (HashAlgorithm hashSHA1 = new SHA1Managed())
using (Stream file = new FileStream(ofdBrowse.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] hash = hashSHA1.ComputeHash(file);

    txtSHA1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: what is txtSHA1? any way try to break the code into bits. `txtSHA1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", ""); ` shall become `var a = BitConverter.ToString(hash);` `var b = a.Replace("-", "");' ' txtSHA1.Text = b;`

Comment: @Nahum Litvin, this doesn't seem to work. This is weird.

Comment: Ok, solved. Reason? My stupidity. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've give *definitely* removes the dashes. Short but complete program to demonstrate that:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (HashAlgorithm hashSHA1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            // Actual data doesn't matter
            using (Stream data = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] hash = hashSHA1.ComputeHash(data);

                Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", ""));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, potential cause of your problem:

- You're not running the build you think you are
- You've got other code which does the hashing but *doesn't* have the `Replace` call
- You're looking at the wrong bit of the UI :)

It's hard to really guess which of those (or anything else) is the problem, but that code isn't it...

Comment: Hmm, I must have some mistype then. I'll double check.

Comment: Ok this is weird. When I do `txtSHA1.Text = "test";` right after `InitializeComponents();` I see the test in correct line. But when I do `txtSHA1.Text = "tesy" + BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);` the text `test` isn't including in the text box.

Comment: Ok, I think i did make a mistake. Thanks anyway. I had the same method twice.. lol

Answer (score 3):

Difference between dash and hyphen?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx

Not really sure.  Just my guess in the dark.